# Eager load delegate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is it possible to eager load (via includes() or similar) a delegated association?

When I try what I hoped would be the obvious solution (assuming ModelA belongs to ModelB, which in turn belongs to Model C):

```
ModelA.includes(:modelB, :modelC)
```

I get an error arising from the fact that ModelA doesn't know about Model C.

I added a delegation to ModelA:

```
delegate :modelC, to: :modelB, allow_nil: false
```

Which allows something like:

```
ModelA.first.modelC
```

But doesn't solve the includes() problem.

How should this be done?

Comment: You shoul use `has_many through` not delegate: Modela has_many ModelB, ModelA has_many ModelC, through: ModelB

Comment: Wrong way around: A belongs to B, B belongs to C. Ideally I want a belongs_to through, but AFAIK that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I believe you could use eager loading

```rb
class ModelA
  delegate :modelC, to: :modelB, allow_nil: false
  belongs_to :modelB
  belongs_to :modelC
end

class ModelB
  has_many :modelAs
  belongs_to :modelC
end

class ModelC
  has_many :modelBs
  has_many :modelAs, through: :modelBs
end
```

What I think you should be able to do is something like (just FYI, I haven't actually ran this myself):

```rb
ModelA.includes(ModelB: :ModelC).first.modelC
```

Some relevant information about this is in the [Rails Guides - Nested Associations Hash](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#nested-associations-hash) and 
[Rails api documention](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes)

I hope this helps!